run only preprocessor using ESP-IDF
I would like to see my esp-idf code after preprocessing (see which code inside of #ifdef will be compiled).
I tried adding "add_compile_optins(-E)" in my main CMake file, but the build failes :(
Anyway I looked in the build dir, and saw .c.obj files (I expected to see .c files).
Is there another way to run only preprocessor? or that ESP-IDF does not support it?
Thanksss

Related: Can gcc output C code after preprocessing?

@WeatherVane not related as he does not want to use -E.

@0___________ it is related, because there is a lot of discussion of the topic, and one answer there is about -save-temps. Plainly this OP would like to use -E because they tried it.

Welcome to SO. Did you try to look into the .c.obj files? Depending on the tool chain, the output name might still be the same if you add -E option but the content changes. That is because the makefile specifies the name and it doesn't know that you don't compile but only preprocess. Then, of course, building fails because the linker will not be happy with what it gets.

The .c.obj files contain other things than the preprocessed code. I would like to see only my code - after preprocessor. Also I want to tell the compiler to stop after preprocessing (don't run the compiler and the linker...)

Anyway you are right, with -E flag the files are more "readable"

What do you mean by "other things"? Do you mean the line number information directives or something else? These are required by the compiler to generated correct debug information. That is what -E produces.

The line number is actually really good for me, but I talk about arguments, structs and names of other files. The code I wrote starts from the middle of this .c.obj file.

hi but the build failes What does it mean exactly? What "fails"? In what way it "fails"? "Fails" is your interpretation of what happens. What happens? what do you see? What is the full verbatim all messages you are getting from your compiler? What is the full verbatim all messages cmake is printing to terminal? What is the output of cmake build --verbose or make VERBOSE=1? What is the exact command line you are using to compile your project? What is the cmake version? What is the compiler version? What are the full exact command line you are using to invoke the compiler?

Of course it contains structs from other files. That is what #include does. It includes the content of the included files in the compiled file. What you find, is what goes into the compiler.

You can use -save-temps option. It should keep .i files (preprocessed files) in the build directory

When I add "-save-temps" it won't compile (without this flag it does), and the .c.obj files are not created- The error is on "heap_caps_init.c".

@bakarbakar "does not compile" without providing complete and exact error message is not a useful information. As it applies to all files, the file name is way less useful than the error message.

The point is that the code can be compiled, but with the flag it doesn't.

@bakarbakar the point is that your comment is 100% useless. Without your error messages no one can tell if you used some option wrong or where the problem is.
